# Does every connected vertex transitive graph on $n$ vertices (except for $C_n$) have minimum feedback vertex set of size $\Omega(n)$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cycles

Feedback vertex set is a set of vertices whose removal leaves an acyclic graph.
It is known that every vertex transitive graph on $n$ vertices has minimum vertex cover of size $\Omega(n)$. It is also not difficult to show that every connected vertex transitive graph (except for the cycle of length $n$) has minimum feedback vertex set 
of size $\Omega(n/\log^2 n)$. Does $\Omega(n)$ bound hold for the same ?

Comment: I guess you mean "minimum feedback vertex set", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d \ge 3$ be the degree of the graph. Then the graph has $dn/2$ edges. In order to make it acyclic we must remove at least $(d/2-1)n$ edges, which in turn implies we must remove $(1/2-1/d)n = \Omega(n)$ vertices. Notice that it suffices to assume the graph is $d$ regular, we don't need transitivity.

Comment: Note also that this is $\Omega(n)$ only if $d>2$; but if $d=2$, then (assuming connectedness) we are in the cycle case that was excluded.  (Indeed, it seems that otherwise, not only do you not need transitivity, you don't even need connectedness.)

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks for pointing this out :-)